# How can I find the tangent plane of this piecewise function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My professor encouraged us to think about the following problem:

Given

$\ f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
          x^2+y^2-2y+1 & x^2=2y \\
          1-2y & x^2\neq2y 
       \end{cases}$

find, if they exist, the tangent planes of $f(x,y)$ for the points:

a) $(x_0,y_0)=(2,2)$

b) $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$

---

I know that the tangent plane equation is:

$Z_t=f(x_0,y_0)+f_x(x_0,y_0)(x-x_0)+f_y(x_0,y_0)(y-y_0)$

My first instinct was to calculate $f_x(2,2)$ and $f_y(2,2)$ for $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-2y+1$, given that $2^2=2(2)$. I found the following tangent plane:

$Z_t=4x+2y-7$

Likewise for $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$, I found:

$Z_t=1-2y$

BUT this appears to be completely wrong. I suspect I need to calculate the partial derivatives of this function applying the definition. For example:

$f_x(2,2)= \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\overbrace{f(x,2)}^{-3}-\overbrace{f(2,2)}^{-5}}{x-2}$

But this limit doesn't exist. I'm confused. Should I conclude that because the partial derivative with respect to $x$ doesn't exist at this point, then the tangent plane doesn't exist either?

If I move on to $(x_0,y_0)=(0,0)$, I think I'm able to calculate the partial derivatives:

$f_x(0,0)= \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}=0$

and

$f_y(0,0)= \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{f(0,y)-f(0,0)}{y}=2$

So I get the following tangent plane:

$Z_t=1-2y$

Which I had found previously. I don't know what to make of that. Where am I going wrong? I could use some guidance

Answer (score 0):

For a function to be differentiable at a certain point, the limit that defines the derivtive needs to exist and be unique (left and right limit). Your function is not continuous at $(x, y) = (2, 2)$, because
$$f(2, 2) = 5 \ne -3 = \lim_{x \to 2, y \to 2} f(x, y)$$
So it's  non-differentiable in that point (It's not even continuous).

For the $(0, 0)$ you don't have such problem, but just to make sure, you should calculate the values and derivatives of both sides ofthe definition at $(0, 0)$ and justify what I said.

Generally speaking you should always check these things at the border of the piecewise definitions.

Comment: There is a bit of a problem at $(0,0)$, since in order to have a tangent plane, the function needs to be differentiable at the point, so it's not enough to just check that the partial derivatives exist. Also, $\lim_{(x,y)\to(2,2)} f(x,y)$ doesn't exist, since you don't get $-3$ if you approach the point along the curve $x^2=2y$. (But of course it's still correct that $f$ is not continuous at that point.)

Comment: This function is differentiable at (0, 0). As I said, "you should calculate the values and derivatives of **both sides** of the definition at (0,0)". I probably should've mentioned 'check the equality'.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is differentiable there, but that's not obvious; you'd have to check it against the definition of differentiability, after you've found the partials at the origin. Also, it's not clear to me what you mean by checking the derivatives of “both sides of the definition” – what exacly does that refer to?